# No access to AWS RDS from AWS ECS Docker Container

Tags: spring, postgresql, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I have a spring boot app packaged in docker image(based on openjdk:8-jdk-alpine). As a datasource i want to use RDS. I configured postgresql RDS instance and i have access to it from my local box.
However when i deploy app to ECS i have the following issue: from EC2 instance i can access 5432 port:

```
nmap -Pn -p 5432 172.31.2.43
...
PORT     STATE SERVICE
5432/tcp open  postgresql
```

But from the docker container started on this instance i cannot access RDS:

```
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
5432/tcp closed postgresql
```

Both RDS and EC2 instance are within same VPC. Security group for RDS allow incoming connections from all ip addresses. I tried to start docker container with --net=host and it didn't help. RDS endpoint seems to be not visible from container

Could anyone suggest what can be adjusted/changed?

Comment: Can you check whether outbound connections going from the container?

Comment: i am running into same issue, any idea how you resolved it?